# ListView disappears when returning to activity after clicking Up button

Tags: android, listview, parse-platform

I'm using Parse.com to populate a ListView in the second activity of my app. Clicking on an item in the ListView opens up a third activity. The problem is that when using the Up button to return to the second activity the ListView is gone. For some reason this behavior does not occur when the Back button is used. Also, it does not occur when just using a normal query in the 2nd activity. Something about the query.whereEqualsTo("department", department) line is throwing the whole thing off.

1st Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private Button mMEButton;
private Button mCEButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mMEButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.meButton);
    mCEButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ceButton);



    mMEButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ProfessorsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("department", "ME");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    mCEButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ProfessorsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("department", "CE");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

2nd Activity:

```
public class ProfessorsActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_professors);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    final String department = intent.getStringExtra("department");

    ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject> factory =
            new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject>() {
                public ParseQuery create() {
                    ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Professor");
                    query.whereEqualTo("department", department);
                    return query;
                }
            };

    adapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject>(this, factory) {
        @Override
        public View getItemView(ParseObject professor, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (v == null) {
                v = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.professor_item, null);
            }
            TextView contentView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.professorNameTextView);
            contentView.setText(professor.getString("lastName") + ", " + professor.getString("firstName"));
            return v;
        }
    };
    //adapter.setTextKey("lastName");
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            final ParseObject tappedProfessor = adapter.getItem(position);
            String professorId = tappedProfessor.getObjectId();

            Intent intent = new Intent(ProfessorsActivity.this, OfficeHoursActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("professorId", professorId);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

3rd Activity:

```
public class OfficeHoursActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private TextView mNameTextView;
private TextView mTimeTextView1;
private TextView mDaysTextView1;
private TextView mTimeTextView2;
private TextView mDaysTextView2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_office_hours);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String professorId = intent.getStringExtra("professorId");

    mNameTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.professorName);
    mTimeTextView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.officeHourTime1);
    mDaysTextView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.officeHourDays1);
    mTimeTextView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.officeHourTime2);
    mDaysTextView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.officeHourDays2);


    mNameTextView.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
    mTimeTextView1.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
    mDaysTextView1.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
    mTimeTextView2.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
    mDaysTextView2.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);


    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Professor");

    // Retrieve the object by id
    query.getInBackground(professorId, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(ParseObject currentProfessor, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                mNameTextView.setText(currentProfessor.getString("lastName") + ", " + currentProfessor.getString("firstName"));
                mTimeTextView1.setText(currentProfessor.getString("start1") + " - " + currentProfessor.getString("end1"));
                mDaysTextView1.setText(currentProfessor.getString("days1"));

                mNameTextView.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                mTimeTextView1.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                mDaysTextView1.setVisibility(VISIBLE);

                if (currentProfessor.getString("start2") != null) {
                    mTimeTextView2.setText(currentProfessor.getString("start2") + " - " + currentProfessor.getString("end2"));
                    mDaysTextView2.setText(currentProfessor.getString("days2"));

                    mTimeTextView2.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                    mDaysTextView2.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                }
            } else {
                //something went wrong
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Put your code of Listview in onresume method.SO that from returning from last activity to your listview activity you can get your data into your listview again thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding the following tag to the second activity within the AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

This prevents the Up button from recreating the activity when it is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

The up button creates a new instance of the parent activity by default.
If you want it to behave as the back button just override "onOptionsItemSelected" in "OfficeHoursActivity" and do the following:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if(item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: This is another valid answer. I changed my second activity so that it has an onNewIntent() method. The "singleTop" launch mode was no longer sufficient for maintaining the list. This code allows me to have the onNewIntent() method and maintain the list in the activity.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void ListView(){
ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject> factory =
            new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject>() {
                public ParseQuery create() {
                    ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Professor");
                    query.whereEqualTo("department", department);
                    return query;
                }
            };

    adapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject>(this, factory) {
        @Override
        public View getItemView(ParseObject professor, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (v == null) {
                v = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.professor_item, null);
            }
            TextView contentView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.professorNameTextView);
            contentView.setText(professor.getString("lastName") + ", " + professor.getString("firstName"));
            return v;
        }
    };
    //adapter.setTextKey("lastName");
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Now call this method from onResume(). Don't call it from onCreate().

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    ListView();

}
```

Now check.. May be you problem will solved..!!!